# How can I install an electric dryer using the old air conditioning circuit in my breaker box

Tags: electrical-panel

I disconnected my central air conditioning unit and I was wondering if it is possible for me to hook up my electric dryer using the circuit breaker that my air conditioning was using.

[image]

Comment: You need the facts.  1) More than likely, an electric dryer needs a 30A 220V circuit.  Is that true in your case? and 2) You need to know the amperage of the now-disabled A/C circuit.  I see only a one 220V breaker in your box - it's the 20A unit at the bottom right.

Comment: What gauge and type of wiring method was used for the existing A/C circuit?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to you question - It is not possible to use any circuit in the panel you are showing unless you want completely replace the AC circuit. I am assuming the 20A 2 pole circuit in the lower right is your AC circuit. Regardless, all of the circuits shown are 20A.

NEC Article 220.14 (B) and (C) prevent you from using a 20A circuit for a dryer load. 220.14 (B) refers you to 220.54 which states all dryer circuits need to be rated for 5000VA, that would be 20.9A at 240V. 220.14 (C) refers you to motor loads which state you have to add 25% for motor start up. So a minimum circuit size for a dryer would be 30A 2 pole with #10 wire conductors.

Hope this helps.